# How to give same id to dictionary if they belong to same network

Tags: javascript

[hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMWi9.jpg)

```
my_dict=[{'s':1,'t':2},
    {'s':2,'t':3},
    {'s':3,'t':1},
    {'s':4,'t':5},
    {'s':5,'t':6},
    {'s':6,'t':4}]
```

convert the above list to

```
output=[{'s':1,'t':2,'id':1},
    {'s':2,'t':3,'id':1},
    {'s':3,'t':1,'id':1},
    {'s':4,'t':5,'id':2},
    {'s':5,'t':6,'id':2},
    {'s':6,'t':4,'id':2}]
```

info - we are giving the same id to the first 3 dictionaries in the list because they belong to the same network. (if you plot graph). same with the next 3 dictionaries

Comment: did you really target `JS` tag? because in JS `list` is `array `and `dictionary`is `object`

Comment: Looks like python code, considering the word "dictionary" and "list" and the single quotes around keys.

Comment: sorry my bad, I work with python as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code it's work:

```
let V;
let adjListArray=[];
let id = 1;
let ids = [];

function Graph(v)
{   
    V = v
    for (let i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        adjListArray.push([]);
    }
}
 
// Adds an edge to an undirected graph
function addEdge(src,dest)
{
    adjListArray[src].push(dest);
    adjListArray[dest].push(src);
}
 
function DFSUtil(v,visited)
{
    visited[v] = true;
    ids[v] = id;
    for (let x = 0; x < adjListArray[v].length; x++)
    {
        if (!visited[adjListArray[v][x]]){
        
            DFSUtil(adjListArray[v][x], visited);
        }

    }
}
 
function connectedComponents()
{
    let visited = new Array(V);
    for(let i = 1; i < V; i++)
    {
        visited[i] = false;
    }
    for (let v = 1; v < V; ++v)
    {
        if (!visited[v])
        {
            DFSUtil(v, visited);
            id++;
            document.write("<br>");
        }
    }
}
 

my_dict=[{'s':1,'t':2},
    {'s':2,'t':3},
    {'s':3,'t':1},
    {'s':4,'t':5},
    {'s':5,'t':6},
    {'s':6,'t':4}];
Graph(my_dict.length + 1);
for(var i = 0 ; i < my_dict.length ; i++){
    addEdge(my_dict[i].s,my_dict[i].t);
}

connectedComponents();
 
for(var i = 0 ; i < my_dict.length ; i++){
   my_dict[i].id = ids[my_dict[i].s];
}
console.log(my_dict);
```

Comment: correction, instead of 
Graph(my_dict.length + 1); we should count number of nodes. in the above example, there are 6 nodes

Comment: you are right, number of nodes is not necessary to equal the length of my_dict

Answer (score 0):

You can use the depth-first search algorithm to calculate each node belonging to any component and this is by iterating the search algorithm on the unvisited nodes.
it's be some like the code in this url:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/

Comment: can you provide me a code

Comment: in python or js?

Comment: i need code in javascript

Comment: well, i will put my code in another answer

Comment: OK, create output dictionary.